# Cannot compile OpenGL code in Mathematica (vc2010-windows 8.1)

Tags: ccompilerdriver

## LinkError of OpenGL

---

My enviroment is windows 8.1 x64, *Mathematica* 9.0.1, opengl 1.1

```
targetDirectory = "E:\\Users\\Hyper\\Documents\\OpenGL";
sourceDirectory = "E:\\Users\\Hyper\\Documents\\OpenGL\\SourceFile";
includeDirectory = {"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\include",    
"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\include\\GL"};
libraryDirectory = {"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\lib"};
LinkerOptions = {"opengl32.lib", "glaux.lib", "glu.lib", "glu32.lib",    "glut.lib", "glut32.lib", "opengl.lib"};

mainFile = Import[sourceDirectory <> "\\opengl-test1.txt"]

(*
    #include <windows.h>   
   //#include <gl/glaux.h>
   //#include <gl/gl.h>
   //#include <gl/glu.h>
  //#include <gl/glut.h>
  #include <glaux.h>
  #include <gl.h>
  #include <glu.h>
  #include <glut.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "glaux.lib")#pragma comment(lib, "glu.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "glut.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "opengl.lib")
  int main(int argc, char* * argv)
{auxInitDisplayMode(AUX_SINGLE|AUX_RGBA);
auxInitPosition(0,0,500,500);
auxInitWindow(argv[0]);
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);
glVertex2f(-0.5,0.5);
glVertex2f(0.5,0.5);
glVertex2f(0.5,-0.5);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}
*)

exe = CreateExecutable[mainFile, "opengl-test1-x64",   "IncludeDirectories" -> includeDirectory, "Language" -> "C++",   "LibraryDirectories" -> libraryDirectory,   "TargetDirectory" -> targetDirectory, "Debug" -> True,   "LinkerOptions" -> LinkerOptions]
```

[image]

---

I can build and run this little example, in VC2010-IDE enviroment, so I'm not sure where goes wrong.

Comment: It looks like several include statements in your mainfile are commented out (using `//`). That may be the problem.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Hi, the commented out include statements are used for include dir=`VC\\include`, I've also include the dir=`VC\\include\\GL` that is ` "E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\include\\GL"}. 
Include errors maybe this : `Cannot open include file: 'glaux.h': No such file or directory `;

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. Why didn't you include those header files?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Sorry, I've reformatted the code, I think now you can understand better.

Comment: Did you take a look at what commands `CreateExecutable` is running? ("ShellCommandFunction").  I would take a look at that, figure out what's wrong with them, and start from there.